# CoreLocation: LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() not working

Tags: swift3, core-location

I'm trying to understand why locationManager continues to provide updates after I've called stopUpdatingLocation()

```
extension ActionViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let newLocation: CLLocation = locations.last!
        print("New Location Accuracy is: \(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)")
        print("Desired Accuracy is: \(locationManager.desiredAccuracy)")
        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
            return
        }

        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy {
            print("We are shutting down location manager")
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            currentLocation = newLocation
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                                              longitude: newLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                                              zoom: zoomLevel)
...
```

Print out from debug area:
New Location Accuracy is: 10.0
Desired Accuracy is: 10.0
We are shutting down location manager
New Location Accuracy is: 10.0
Desired Accuracy is: 10.0
We are shutting down location manager
New Location Accuracy is: 10.0
Desired Accuracy is: 10.0
We are shutting down location manager
New Location Accuracy is: 702.317035988665
Desired Accuracy is: 10.0
New Location Accuracy is: 702.318123337466
Desired Accuracy is: 10.0
New Location Accuracy is: 10.0
Desired Accuracy is: 10.0
We are shutting down location manager

Comment: I think you should call `manager.stopUpdatingLocation()` instead of `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure `"We are shutting down location manager"` is printed?

Comment: Yes.  It's printed multiple times which is the heart of the problem.

Comment: Does it stop reporting locations after a short while?

Comment: @shallowThought.  It does stop after a short while.  After many hours of research, I believe I've found the answer, which I'll post now.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent many hours searching for the answer and I believe I've found it.  Apparently, after calling stopUpatingLocation, it takes a few seconds for the GPS antennae to power down.  Someone posted that this was discussed at a WWDC.

[Here is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875274/does-the-internal-gps-antenas-stop-working-immediately-after-calling-cllocationm)